# Can you reuse options defined in other commands using commander.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

So I have several commands and they all use the same options.

For example..

```
program.command('hello')
    .option('--foo <name>', 'this is the foo option and requires a name')
    .option('--bar', 'this is the bar option and takes no arguments')
    .action(options => {
        // do stuff here...
    });

program.command('world')
    .option('--foo <name>', 'this is the foo option and requires a name')
    .option('--bar', 'this is the bar option and takes no arguments')
    .action(options => {
        // do stuff here...
    });
```

I'd like to refactor this and define the options once. However, action taken for each command may differ.

Is there a way to declare options once and use them for any/all commands defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your shared command, then you can add to it the specific configuration.

**Initialize your shared item:**

```js
const createCommandWithSharedOptions = () => new program.Command()
    .option('--foo <name>', 'this is the foo option and requires a name')
    .option('--bar', 'this is the bar option and takes no arguments')
```

**Define your custom command based on the shared init:**

```js
const hello = createCommandWithSharedOptions().name('hello').arguments('<req> [opt]')
const world = createCommandWithSharedOptions().name('world')
```

**Add them to the `program`:**

```js
program.addCommand(hello).addCommand(world)
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you, choosing this as preferred solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with only works for commands that have the same exact options. To work with unique options, you would have to probably extend the solution I found, or maybe there is another way as well.

What I came up with:

```
[
    {
        name: 'hello',
        method: 'hiMethod'
    },
    {
        name: 'world',
        method: 'woMethod',
    },
].forEach(cmd => {
    program.command(cmd.name)
        .option('--foo <name>', 'this is the foo option and requires a name')
        .option('--bar', 'this is the bar option and takes no arguments')
        .action(options => {
            // do stuff here...
            // I can use `cmd.method` for unique actions for each command
        });
});
```

This solution worked for me :)